# Kendo UI for angular &nbsp; char is exported as text to PDF

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, export-to-pdf

I have a problem with chart exporting to pdf. When changing chart size I need to add some empty lines to chart labels to make with not overlap with each other. But when I export chart as PDF I have this `&nbsp;` text in label. Is there any fix for this?

```
function labelTemplate(e) {
  var ds = $("#chart").data("kendoChart").dataSource;
  var index = ds.indexOf(e.dataItem);
  var label = index % 2 !== 0 ? "&nbsp;\n" : ""; 
  label += e.value;
  return label;
}
```

Comment: You added a tag for `kendo-ui-angular2`. Are you using Angular 2+?

Comment: Why are you using `&nbsp;` and not just a space?